# How can I code a pause/play functionality with jquery tools scrollable, when it has autoscroll enabled?

Tags: jquery, scrollable

```
 var scrollableApi = $("#products").scrollable({circular: true, speed: 20000, easing: 'linear'}).autoscroll({interval: 0}).data('scrollable')


$('#products').hover(function() {
   scrollableApi.pause();
},function() {
   scrollableApi.play();
})
```

The code above is what I tried, but it just doesn't want to work.Any ideas are welcommed.

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean?

Comment: Yes. So there is an infinite scroll effect of my products, it scrolls from right to left then it start over. I just want to implement a pause on the scroll when I mouse over it, so it stops and when I go out with the mouse of it, it continues to scroll. The problem is that the code above does not stop the scroller.

Comment: Did you check the console on browser?

Comment: Yes, nothing about that code. This is the website: http://vandiermen.com/products

Comment: @JozsefKerekes, your clarifications are helpful, but they'd be more helpful as edits to your question instead of comments.